# Django: Why is this output HTML-escaped

Tags: django, templates

In my template I'm writing:

```
<div class="content video">{{ each.text }}</div>
```

And I'm getting:

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1C1HLH-hOZU" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want that text to be the part of the mark up,not as text.What say?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you mean the output of `each.text` is escaped and you see the text in your browser rather than the rendered markup?

This is because Django's template engine autoescapes output by default for security reasons. You might want to use the builtin `safe` filter like this:

```
<div class="content video">{{ each.text|safe }}</div>
```

Or another way is to use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) in your view.